# Arduino send a HEX

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to print a HEX with `Serial.print();`

```
Serial.write("HEX Code: %x", 0xFFF);
```

I tried this. I thought maybe it's like in C with printf.
Any ideas how I can write the HEX?

Comment: So this does not work? What happens, then?

Comment: Example: `Serial.print(78, HEX) gives "4E"`

Comment: You should really spend some time [reading the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin normally you are right. But it's just for this week. I don't continue working with Arduino after this week...

Comment: it would take much less time, headache and effort than what you're putting in this project already.. i can see you sweat from here :)

Comment: @Bundeskanzler I disagree. Finding a way to find yourself the answer is ALWAYS the fastest and smartest way of solving a problem. See this question as example: it took you maybe a couple of minutes to open SO, write your question and post it. Then it took the fastest answers some more couple of minutes (just because this is an easy question) to arrive here. Then you had to read it, answer the comments, and so on. This is a trivial question, again, and yet it took you 10-15 minutes to get a reply. The other way: open the docs, search for serial, see the print and println functions, ... continue

Comment: continue... read their documentation and examples, get a completely working example in maybe 5 minutes, which can be shortened with google. The fastest way to solve a problem is always by doing it yourself, unless the problem is actually complicated (but admit this, you already knew this was simple). So IMHO the problem is not "it's faster asking here", it is just laziness

Comment: @frarugi87 you are right, for that question. But a other question, I searched 5 hours and found no solution. (At the moment I also have no solution for the question)

Comment: @Bundeskanzler. so if you search the web, read the manuals, try and see that it is not behaving like you think, then yes, you should ask the others. OT: I couldn't find which question was not answered, but I found that you are a bit confused about base conversion. There is no such thing as the base. `int a = 13` and `int b = 0xD` will make a and b have EXACTLY the same representation. You can't convert 0x00FF to 255, because it is already that way. Different is the case where you are dealing with strings, but you should specify that in the question ("0x00FF" is different from "255")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Serial.print("HEX Code: ");
Serial.println(0xFFFF, HEX);
```

see more examples here:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print

Comment: +1, However, it would important to mention that `write` sends out data in **raw format** (aka bytes), whereas `print/println` converts values to their *textual representation*.

Comment: @Bundeskanzler. You can convert hex value from int to be in a string by using `string str = String.Format("0x%x", 0xFFFF);`

Answer (score 1):

You're sending invalid characters.

It's simply:

Serial.write(0xFFF);

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=142248.0

Comment: Have a look here: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=433237.0   Tells you how to read a packet (8-bytes) and each byte would be a hex value, or scroll further down - shows you have to continously scan reading a hex value at a time as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: +1, However, it would important to mention that `write` sends out data in **raw format** (aka bytes), whereas `print/println` converts values to their *textual representation*.

Comment: OP wants to send a hexadecimal representation of the integer. `Serial.write(0xFFF);` send s a raw byte `0xFF`, since `Serial.write` can only send a byte.

Comment: How did this completely wrong answer get 2 upvotes?